# Docker API: Listening to events

Tags: python, docker

I would like to list Docker events using its API, so I created this class:

This is the simplest form of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests_unixsocket
import json

session = requests_unixsocket.Session()
resp = session.get("http+unix://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/events")

print resp
```

When I run the script and create a Docker network in another terminal, I am supposed to see something like that:

```
{"Type":"network","Action":"create","Actor":{"ID":"20f9f862aa509bdd2b147252c3cb50f035b1e7b36542c9f7fad4ccbce0206507","Attributes":{"name":"network15","type":"bridge"}},"time":1481387403,"timeNano":1481387403635383908}
```

But I don't see anything happening, it seems like the program is listening in a infinite loop but not showing anything like I said.

Do you have an idea on how to stream these events and show them on my terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something. Adding `stream = True` resolved the problem:

```
session.get( self.base + self.url, stream= True)
```